# Convert distance on MKMapView to distance for UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

How do I convert distance (for example 400 meters) on MKMapView to distance for UIView?
I want to show MKAnnotationView that depends on current zoom level on MKMapView.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, create a region with 400 meters length:

```
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.centerCoordinate, 400, 0);
```

After that use convert region methods for getting real rect:

```
CGRect myRect = [mapView convertRegion: myRegion toRectToView: nil];
NSLog(@"width for 400m is %f", myRect.size.width);
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: if you set the distance as the `latitudinalMeters` attribute for `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`, as in your example, you should really read the height not the width of the resulting `CGRect`. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance

Answer (score 5):

You have several selectors in [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) to convert UIView coordinates on the screen to geo coordinates (and geo -> screen as well):

```
- (CGPoint)convertCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate toPointToView:(UIView *)view
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toCoordinateFromView:(UIView *)view
```

I assume 400 meters is a distance between 2 coordinates, so should you have a reference to 2 `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structures.
Just use `- (CGPoint)convertCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate toPointToView:(UIView *)view` to get the corresponding `CGPoint` (= screen coordinates) and you should be then able to calculate the screen distance.