# Pixels for meter length in MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am trying to create a function that takes in a parameter of meters and returns a pixel width for an MKMapView.

How can I correctly determine from the current zoom of the map, how many pixels represent the correct amount of meters?

So an example is let's say I have a zone radius of 78 meters, and the current distance across the map is 6000 meters.  How can I represent those 78 meters as a scaled proportional UIView on the map?

My plan was to first calculate how many meters across the map are currently being represented. So here is what I have for that. But I am getting stuck on trying to figure out how to convert the amount of meters into the correct pixel widths. I already have the correct zone radiuses as well.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    MKMapRect currentRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;
    MKMapPoint farEastPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMinX(currentRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(currentRect));
    MKMapPoint farWestPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(currentRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(currentRect));
    double currentDis =MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(farEastPoint, farWestPoint);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412088/convert-distance-on-mkmapview-to-distance-for-uiview.  But why not add an overlay like an MKCircle to the map view instead (the map view will then take care of scaling and moving the zone region for you)?

Comment: Because I am trying to add animations to the view

Comment: Then the `convertRegion:toRectToView:` method as the linked answer mentions will help.  Just be sure to specify the proper view for the ToView: parameter.  If your UIView is a subview of the map's parent VC (eg. self.view), then ToView: should be self.view.  I don't recommend adding a subview to the map view directly.

Comment: What I decided to do was create a map annotation and have subview on the map annotation. I got the correct width I needed by using         MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(map.centerCoordinate,radius.floatValue,radius.floatValue);
        CGRect myRect = [map convertRegion: region toRectToView: nil];