# Convert distance on UIView to distance for MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, cgrect

Basically, I'm trying to to the opposite of [Convert distance on MKMapView to distance for UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412088/convert-distance-on-mkmapview-to-distance-for-uiview).

I have a distance in UI View, and want to convert it to a distance of MK-MapView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just go to the documentation? You clearly haven't in this case.

If you had you would have found the method...

```
- (MKCoordinateRegion)convertRect:(CGRect)rect
                 toRegionFromView:(UIView *)view
```

Which is the one after the method in the linked question.

So just reverse the process from the linked question using this method.

[Documentation for MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/convertRegion:toRectToView:)

BTW, to find the documentation for any class just put the class name into Google. The first link (most of the time) will be a link to the Apple documentation.

Comment: That's why half of posts in objc section are below zero. Nobody read docs anymore.

Comment: thanks a lot. I have found this method in the documentation, but didn't quite know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Fogmeister and [iOS how to calculate size width to meters in every region(any location and any zoom)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968030/ios-how-to-calculate-size-width-to-meters-in-every-regionany-location-and-any-z), my code is the following:

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 400);
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion= [mapView convertRect:myRect toRegionFromView:mapView];
CLLocationDegrees deltaLatitude = myRegion.span.latitudeDelta;
CLLocationDegrees deltaLongitude = myRegion.span.longitudeDelta;
CGFloat latitudeCircumference = 40075160 * cos(mapView.region.center.latitude * M_PI / 180);
NSLog(@"x: %f; y: %f", deltaLongitude * latitudeCircumference / 360, deltaLatitude * 40008000 / 360);
```

y should contain the distance in meters. Do you know if I made any mistakes?

Comment: latitudeDelta is the change in latitude over that region. You now need to convert that span into metres. (Hint, google will help).